# Editing the info window of google map through iframe url

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to bring some changes in google map info window through it's iframe url?

For instance, adding `“&amp;iwloc=near”` to the end of the following iframe src url remove the info window from the google map.

```
<iframe width=”300″ height=”300″ frameborder=”0″ scrolling=”no” marginheight=”0″
marginwidth=”0″
src=”http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=cb22+7np&amp;sll=52.127428,0.16816&amp;sspn=0.22552,0.676346&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Harston+CB22+7NP,+United+Kingdom&amp;t=k&amp;ll=52.138335,0.073814&amp;spn=0.015804,0.025749&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed”>
</iframe>
```

Can anyone tell which attributes in the above iframe url are responsible for displaying the tick marked links in the info window of the following image?

[image]

In code view this links are wrapped in a `ul` class named `.actbar-list`.

Is it possible to remove these links or manage these links open in new windows by editing the iframe url?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't look like the parts of `InfoWindow`, you ticked, can be changed.

`iwloc`, `iwd`, `iwstate1` are the parameters that seem to have any control over the `InfoWindow`. But these parameters don't seem to control the elements you highlighted in the image. These parameters are not publicly documented anymore. Third party link [here](http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters).

But if you are using dynamic google maps APIv3, it might be possible to tailor an [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) yourself while click event on [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) is detected.

But if you are creating a map view using the dynamic API, you would have already known that.

Here's a link to the Google Maps Dynamic API page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: The documentation is for the static (image) version of maps, but the question was about the dynamic map API.

Comment: `Can anyone tell which attributes in the above iframe url are responsible for displaying the tick marked links in the info window of the following image?` , that doesn't sound like asking about dynamic API

Comment: The given URL in the code sample is a dynamic Google Map, and "image" refers to the screenshot below the text. Also the posting refers to "HTML Elements in Info Windows" that are not possible in static maps.

Comment: That's a screen shot of dynamic map. So no useful reference about it.